# 8 Tile Puzzle via BFS

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, sliding-tile-puzzle

I have searched the depths of the internet and I am yet to find a solution to my problem. I have implemented(I think) a BFS for the sliding tile game. However, It cannot solve a problem unless the state is a few steps away otherwise it just results in Out of Memory errors.
So my question to you, where am I going wrong? AFAIK my code follows the BFS pseudo code.

EDIT/NOTE: I have stepped through with a debugger and have yet to find anything out of the ordinary to my eye but I am merely a novice programmer comparatively.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Search Algorithm:  Breadth-First Search 
//
// Move Generator:  
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class State{
public:
    int state[9];

    State(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            state[i] = i;
        }
    }

    State(string st){
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++){
            state[i] = st.at(i) - '0';
        }
    }

    State(const State &st){
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            state[i] = st.state[i];
        }
    }

    bool operator==(const State& other) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if (this->state[i] != other.state[i]){return false;}
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!=(const State& other) {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    void swap(int x, int y){
        // State b; // blank state
        // for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) // fill blank state with current state
        //  b.state[i] = state[i];

        int t = this->state[x]; // saves value of the value in position x of the state

        this->state[x] = this->state[y]; // swaps value of position x with position y in the state
        this->state[y] = t; // swaps value of position y with saved position x in the state
    }

    int findBlank(){ // finds position in 3x3 of blank tile
        for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
            if (state[i]==0) return i;
        }
    }

    vector<State> blankExpand(){
        int pos = this->findBlank();
        vector<State> vecStates;


        if (pos != 0 && pos != 1 && pos != 2){ // swaps the tile above it
            State newState = State(*this);
            newState.swap(pos,pos - 3);
            vecStates.push_back(newState);
        }

        if (pos != 6 && pos != 7 && pos != 8){ // swaps the tile above it
            State newState = State(*this);
            newState.swap(pos,pos + 3);
            vecStates.push_back(newState);
        }

        if (pos != 0 && pos != 3 && pos != 6){ // swaps the tile above it
            State newState = State(*this);
            newState.swap(pos,pos - 1);
            vecStates.push_back(newState);
        }

        if (pos != 2 && pos != 5 && pos != 8){ // swaps the tile above it
            State newState = State(*this);
            newState.swap(pos,pos + 1);
            vecStates.push_back(newState);
        }

        return vecStates;
    }
};

string breadthFirstSearch_with_VisitedList(string const initialState, string const goalState){
    string path;

  clock_t startTime;
  startTime = clock();

  deque<State> nodesToVisit;
  vector<State> visitedList;
  int maxQLength = 0;


  //Init
    State init(initialState);
    State goal(goalState);
    nodesToVisit.push_back(init);

    int count = 0;
    int numOfStateExpansions = 0 ;
//
    while (!nodesToVisit.empty()){
        if(maxQLength < nodesToVisit.size()){maxQLength = nodesToVisit.size();}

        State cur = nodesToVisit.front();
        nodesToVisit.pop_front();
         //remove front

        if (cur == goal){
            //solution found
            cout << "solved!";
            break;
        }

        //Get children
        vector<State> children = cur.blankExpand();

        numOfStateExpansions += children.size();        

        //For each child
        for (State& child : children) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 9;i++){
                cout << child.state[i];
            }
            cout << " child" << endl;

          //If already visited ignore
          if (std::find(visitedList.begin(), visitedList.end(), child) != visitedList.end()) {
            // cout << "duplicate" << endl;
            continue;
          }

          //If not in nodes to Visit
          else if (std::find(nodesToVisit.begin(), nodesToVisit.end(), child) == nodesToVisit.end()) {
            //Add child
            nodesToVisit.push_back(child);
          }
        }
        visitedList.push_back(cur);

    }



//***********************************************************************************************************
    clock_t actualRunningTime = ((float)(clock() - startTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);  
    return path;    

}

int main(){
    breadthFirstSearch_with_VisitedList("042158367", "123804765");
    //042158367
}

// 0 4 2
// 1 5 8
// 3 6 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of inneficiencies in your code that are slowing it down. I'm actually surprised you had the patience to wait for it to reach an out-of-memory condition.

The main culprits are the searches:

`std::find(visitedList.begin(), visitedList.end(), child) != visitedList.end()
//and
std::find(nodesToVisit.begin(), nodesToVisit.end(), child) == nodesToVisit.end()`

Both of these execute in O(N), which sounds fine, but since you execute them on every node, that results in a O(N<sup>2</sup>).

You can fix this by using a `std::unordered_set<>` for the `visitedList`. Also, you could add nodes to the `visited_list` as soon as you queue them (instead of when you dequeue them). This way, you would only have a single lookup to do.

N.B. You will have to specialize `std::hash<State>` in order to use `std::unordered_set`.

One more hint: these `cout << ...` in your main loop really slow you down because they force a flush and sync with the OS by default, commenting these out will make your program run a lot faster.

There's actually quite a few more improvements that could be made in your code, but that's a topic for another day. Fixing the algorithmic complexity will bring it in the non-broken realm of things.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, the cout is just from me purely doing a bit of debugging and not their to be useful. I will change my current and see what happens. I didnt wait for it to Out of Memory but I knew after 15 Secs that would be the likely outcome. I originally tested with unordered sets but was unsure how to implement and just went to a vector.

Comment: @RyanMason 15 seconds is nothing for a BFS, It could conceivably run  for an hour without hitting an actual out of memory and successfully finding the right solution whith your version of the code. You really should ammend your question and describe the behavior you are seeing instead of your assumptions.

Comment: after doing some research on unsorted_set, would it be beneficial to use a unsorted_map instead?

Comment: @RyanMason An `unsorted_map<>` creates a mapping between keys and values. If `State` is the key, what would the value be?

Comment: Okay I see, so to implement the unsorted_map, the most common method I have seen is to create a struct 'hash' that overloads operator().Now do I need to do this. I already overload my comaprison operator but can I use the default hasher on the state or do I need to reconstruct my int array into a hashable variable.

Comment: @RyanMason, yes, that's what I mean by "specialize std::hash<State>".

Comment: I have written most of the struct, the only part I am unsure is what do I hash from my object. Can I hash my entire array or do I need to change my comparison to check for a matching string/int so I can then hash a string/int inside my struct

Comment: @RyanMason You need to come up with a way to assign a unique value of `std::size_t` for each possible board state, it should be fairly easy to do.

Comment: I have made a hasher function but I have some errors that I cant seem to work out how to fix. https://hastebin.com/ehepafeguz.cpp if you could take a look that would be awesome.